# HTML-based Adobe Air Application for Playbook - Cannot read property of "SQLConnection" of undefined

Tags: jquery, adobe, air, blackberry-playbook

I'm having some real problems getting a HTML-based Adobe Air application to run correctly.  I've been developing it in Aptana, and executing it through there is working a treat - no errors whatsoever.  The problem occurs when I try to run the same file through Chrome, Firefox (or most importantly) the BlackBerry Playbook simulator.
When I try to run my app in any of these environments, it looks as though the jquery isn't running.  If I use Chrome to inspect element and view the .js file, it is coming up with two errors - "Uncaught TypeError - Cannot read property 'SQLConnection' of undefined" and "Uncaught TypeError - Cannot read property 'File' of undefined.

Any idea what normally causes these errors?  The HTML file is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Application Sandbox sample</title>
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/air/AIRAliases.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="topBar">
                <h2 class="tripbar_title">Tripbook logo</h2>
                <h2 class="tripbar_subtitle">Travel Tracking Made Simple</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="main">
                <ul id="navigation">
                    <a href="pages/menu.html" class="log_on_link"><li class="log_on_text">Log-on as <b class="first_name_text">First_Name</b> <b class="last_name_text">Last_Name</b> of <b class="company_name_text">Company_Name</b></li></a>
                    <a href="pages/register.html" class="register_link"><li class="register_link_text">Register a new user</li></a>
                    <a href="pages/switch_user.html" class="switch_user_link"><li class="switch_user_link_text">Switch Users</li></a>
                    <a href="pages/company.html" class="switch_employer_link"><li class="switch_employer_link_text">Switch Job</li></a>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/welcome.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the javascript file (welcome.js) starts:

```
// Bootstrap
$(document).ready(function(){
    SetupDB();
    displayMenu();
    SuggestUser();
});

var log_in_first;
var log_in_last;
var log_in_company; 
var db = new air.SQLConnection(); 


function SetupDB(){

    var dbFile = air.File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("tripbook_base.db"); 
    if (!dbFile.exists) { //
        var dbTemplate = air.File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("tripbook_base.db");
        dbTemplate.copyTo(dbFile, true);
        }  //
        try {
            db.open(dbFile);
        } 
        catch (error) {
            air.trace("DB error:", error.message);
            air.trace("Details:", error.details);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symbol "air" is not defined.  Therefore the statement:

```
var db = new air.SQLConnection();
```

will not work. I don't know what that "AIRAliases.js" file is, but if you expect it to define the symbol "air" for you, it apparently isn't working.

*edit* — ok googling for "AIRAliases.js" indicates that it contains some "convenience" renaming of some Air facilities. Thus it's probably not the direct problem. I suspect the issue is that you're trying to load your HTML and JavaScript directly into a browser, expecting it to be able to use the facilities that it uses in Air. It can't.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, and I think you're exactly right.  Just dug through the incredibly confusing Playbook documentation, it seems I should be using the HTML5 Web Database API instead.